# Fixing A bug for Valgrind for false memory leaks

Tags: c++, ubuntu, memory-leaks, valgrind

I just as of yesterday installed Ubuntu(terminal) on my windows computer. In addition, when ahead and installed Valgrind, "sudo apt install Valgrind", to test everything out I went ahead and create a c++ hello world program. Then tested it with Valgrind. The Valgrind said I had about "72,704 bytes in 1 block". Further research, I performed suggested this was a bug of Valgrind with the c++ standard library functions, possible the iostream. My question is how do I go about fixing this bug. I can't ignore because if I am working on programs I need to able to accurately gauge where it's coming from. If anyone can provide a step by step solution for my problem in layman's term for the problem it would be invaluable.
here is my code and errors I get:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main() {
        cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

==195== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==195== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==195== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==195== Command: ./helloworld
==195==
Hello World
==195==
==195== HEAP SUMMARY:
==195==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==195==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 76,800 bytes allocated
==195==
==195== LEAK SUMMARY:
==195==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==195==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==195==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==195==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==195==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==195== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==195==
==195== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==195== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

update :
Seems like I can sort deal with the false positive leaks by creating suppression files. However, I am not as tech savvy compared some people on here to know how to do that. How would I create suppression files on Valgrind (specifically for my situation)? Please explain it in LAYMAN's terms and please be as detailed as possible.
second update:
I have been semi-successful in suppressing the memory leaks but I would like to know if there is a more viable long term solution out there.

Comment: Most likely it is one of dl-related false positive leak reports.

Comment: Okay how do I fix it?

Comment: Can it even be fixed?

Comment: These problems have been around for years and still aren't fixed.

Comment: What am I to do? Surely there is a way to get around this.

Comment: Could you please **edit your question** to remove images and show both the source code and the output as indented text. Each code line should start with four spaces at least.

Comment: You could try to compare the output with [Dr.Memory](http://www.drmemory.org). You may get a more detailed report. The result may even be not a false positive. Still, the OS will free all memory still open at program termination. The real question is whether the function that allocated the not freed memory is called more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that these are most likely genuine issues, but probably too minor for the libc/libstdc++ developers to fix.

You can generate suppressions in the Valgrind output by specifying `--gen-suppressions=yes`. This will generate output like this:

```
==28328== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 7
==28328==    at 0x4C290F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==28328==    by 0x4111D8: xmalloc (xmalloc.c:43)
==28328==    by 0x41120B: xmemdup (xmalloc.c:115)
==28328==    by 0x40F899: clone_quoting_options (quotearg.c:102)
==28328==    by 0x40742A: decode_switches (ls.c:1957)
==28328==    by 0x40742A: main (ls.c:1280)
==28328== 
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   fun:malloc
   fun:xmalloc
   fun:xmemdup
   fun:clone_quoting_options
   fun:decode_switches
   fun:main
}
```

In the above, the section with the pid (==28328==) is the usual output. The section after it (delimited by braces) is the generated suppression. You can copy this block into a file, for instance `my_suppressions`, and then you can run valgrind and tell it to read the file `--suppressions=my_suppressions`.

If you are planning on maintaining your suppressions file for a long time, then it is best to put some meaningful (and unique) text in the place of 'insert_a_suppression_name_here'. This will help you monitor which suppressions are being used, since if you run valgrind in verbose mode (-v or --verbose) it will list all of the used suppressions. For instance

```
--30822-- used_suppression:      2 Example for SO my_suppressions:2 suppressed: 112 bytes in 2 blocks
--30822-- used_suppression:      4 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object /remote/us01home48/pfloyd/tools/vg313/lib/valgrind/default.supp:1431
```

Comment: Is there an extension I would use like "vim my_suppression.rc" or something. In addition, I didn't mention this but I have tried generating an suppression "valgrind -gen-suppressions=all ./helloworld" but it only gives the output that I posted.

Comment: okay, i had to do some additionals for my suppression file to work, but is there a more long term solution. I don't think I am the only one who encountered this problem, before so there must be a n more viable solution then suppression

Comment: My mistake, that should have been 'yes' not 'all' (answer amended). Personally I use something like `--log-file=app_valgrind.%p` so that the Valgrind output goes to a file. This makes it easier to copy to the suppression file.

Comment: could be more specific. Would I type "valgrind --log-<insert file here>=app_valgrind.%p"? By the way, I also tried it with yes.

Comment: Okay I tried this on a linux vm, and it worked. I am not sure if this unique to my pc or this is a global issue.

Comment: The doc for --log-file is in the core arguments section here. http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.options. I use %p for the pid and an app specific prefix.